# FATAL: password authentication failed for user / but user exist

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql

I'm banging my head against a wall here. I need another set of eyes.
This is error I get:

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication
>   failed for user "localproject" FATAL:  password authentication failed
>   for user "localproject"

I have set up the database like this in the settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'project',
        'USER': 'localproject',
        'PASSWORD': 'MahPassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

And I have created the Scheme like this:

> postgres=# CREATE DATABASE project;

Set the user like this:

> postgres=# CREATE USER localproject WITH PASSWORD 'MahPassword';

Set the priviligies for the scheme like this:

> postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE project TO
>   localproject ;

And the database list looks like this:

> postgres=# \l
>
> ```
>                                List of databases
> Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |    Access privileges
> -----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+------------------------
>  project   | postgres | UTF8     | en_CA.UTF-8 | en_CA.UTF-8 |=Tc/postgres           +
>        |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres  +
>        |          |          |             |             | localproject=CTc/postgres
> ```

Why on earth do I get the error?

Comment: can you try `DROP DATABASE project; CREATE DATABASE project OWNER localproject;`?

Comment: @BearBrown Yes, but I get same result.

Answer (score 0):

It works after restart.

Restart by using this line:

> sudo service postgresql restart

Comment: That can only make a difference if you changed a configuration file.

Comment: Maybe so. But it still solved it for me. I haven't changed any configurations files or anything else. I have only tried dropping scheme, remove user, add user, change priviligies. Nothing worked until I restarted postgresql.